# Arrays.fill() only allowed in method?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using a book to self-study Java.  One of my exercises needs an array with boolean values.   When I try to use `Arrays.fill(myArray, false)` as indicated below I get a compiler errors.  Plus the IDE complains.

```
...\ArrayFill.java:6: <identifier> expected
...\ArrayFill.java:6: <identifier> expected
...\ArrayFill.java:6: illegal start of type
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayFill {

boolean[] myArray = new boolean[4];   // Declaration OK.
Arrays.fill( myArray, false);         // Not OK.

//    boolean[] myArray = {false, false, false, false }; // Manually OK.

public void makeReservation(){
    Arrays.fill(myArray, false);      // In a method, OK.
}

}
```

It seems like it has something to do with the fact that `Arrays.fill` is a static method but I can't find the answer why.  Am I close?

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with `Arrays.fill` specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code that can be directly inside a class is declarations and static initializers. Note that `Arrays.fill(myArray, false);` is neither of these, so it must be inside another block of code, specifically a constructor, method, or static initializer.

Comment: Thank-you.  Odd to me that I've never run into before but you are right.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot run arbitrary statements outside a method body.

You need to put your code in a constructor, initializer block, or main method.